# addClass not updating css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My add class isn't updating? I'm trying to make a sticky nav, and my site isn't updating the css. None of the existing questions seem to help. The site is [antetech.org](http://antetech.org)

Html:

```
<nav id = 'main-nav'>
         <a href="/index.php"><img class = 'logo' src='CSS/IMG/logo.png' alt='Logo'></a>

                <ul>
                   <li><a href='#home'> <button class="bttn-stretch bttn-md bttn-primary" >Home</button> </a> </li>
                   <li><a href='#about'><button class="bttn-stretch bttn-md bttn-primary"> About </button></a></li>
                   <li><a href='#downloads'> <button class="bttn-stretch bttn-md bttn-primary">Software</button> </a> </li>
                   <li><a href='/support.php'><button class="bttn-stretch bttn-md bttn-primary"> Tech Support </button></a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav .onscroll{
background: rgba(173, 9, 26, 0.5);
}
```

Jquery/javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).on('scroll', function(){
         if($(window).scrollTop()){
             $('nav').addClass('onscroll');
             $('nav').removeClass('default');
         }
         else 
             {
              $('nav').removeClass('onscroll');
              $('nav').addClass('default');
             }
     })
    </script>
```

On chrome, it shows the class updating, but nothing is changing. Not just specifically with the background color, but with any changes.

Answer (score 6):

Your Javascript is working fine and as expected, it is your CSS that is incorrect.

You need to update the selector `nav .onscroll` in style.css to `nav.onscroll` - i.e. no space between nav and the class name. This is because you are applying the class *on* the nav, by using a space it denotes that .onscroll is a child element of nav.

So your CSS should be

```
nav.onscroll{
    background: rgba(173, 9, 26, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Okay I fixed that, and that did work, but the background still isn't changing?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS declaration as below (remove nav):

```
.onscroll{ background: rgba(173, 9, 26, 0.5); }
```